# How to determine if Native JavaScript Object has a Property/Method?

Tags: javascript, methods, properties, native, typeof

I thought this would be as easy as:

```
if(typeof(Array.push) == 'undefined'){
  //not defined, prototype a version of the push method
  // Firefox never gets here, but IE/Safari/Chrome/etc. do, even though
  // the Array object has a push method!
}
```

And it does work fine in Firefox, ***but not in IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera***, they return all properties/methods of the native Array object as 'undefined' using this test.

The .hasOwnProperty( prop ) method only works on instances... so it doesn't work, but by trial and error I noticed that this works.

```
//this works in Firefox/IE(6,7,8)/Chrome/Safari/Opera
if(typeof(Array().push) == 'undefined'){
  //not defined, prototype a version of the push method
}
```

Is there anything wrong with using this syntax to determine if a property/method exists on a *Native Object / ~"JavaScript Class"~*, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, typeof is an operator, not a function, so you don't need the parentheses.  Secondly, access the object's prototype.

```
alert( typeof Array.prototype.push );
alert( typeof Array.prototype.foo );
```

When you execute `typeof Array.push` you are testing if the Array object itself has a push method, not if instances of Array have a push method.

Comment: Interesting... I read that .prototype was only for adding new properties/methods to objects, I didn't think to use typeof on it. e.g.
prototype http://www.devguru.com/technologies/JavaScript/10764.asp
typeof http://www.devguru.com/technologies/JavaScript/11529.asp

Comment: It's for that, yes, but not ONLY for that.  I recommend watching Douglas Crockford's presentation on "Advanced Javascript" in the YUI Theater (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/) - there's some great "under the hood" stuff there, including how object prototypes work.

Comment: this will not see the properties defined in parent prototypes

Comment: This won't work with all cases. For example (typeof XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onload !== 'undefined') throws a TypeError: Illegal invocation. The correct way is to: ('onload' in XMLHttpRequest.prototype)

Answer (score 62):

The proper way to check if a property exists:

```
if ('property' in objectVar)
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to check if 'AddFavorite' exists in window.external, so far this:

alert('AddFavorite' in window.external);

is the only script that works!

thanks

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it works in all cases, unlike the current accepted answer.

Comment: In my case it work only if I use it like that: `"prop" in ObjectClass.prototype`, but not when `"prop" in ObjectClass`

Answer (score 8):

The `.hasOwnProperty` can be accessed on the Array's proptotype, if `typeof` is not idiomatic enough.

```
if (Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty('push')) {
    // Native array has push property
}
```

Comment: good option - just need to make sure that this isn't tested on DOM elements in older versions of IE without checking first if the object has the `.hasOwnProperty()` method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/328kyd6z%28VS.85%29.aspx#CommunityContentHeader

Answer (score 3):

> And it does work fine in Firefox

That's only by coincidence! You can't generally expect a prototype's method to also exist on the constructor function.

> ```
> if(typeof(Array().push) == 'undefined')
> ```

This was nearly right except you forget `new`, a perennial JavaScript gotcha. `new Array().push`, or `[].push` for short, would correctly check an instance had the method you wanted.