# How to check if anonymous object has a method?

Tags: javascript

How can I check if an anonymous object that was created as such:

```
var myObj = { 
    prop1: 'no',
    prop2: function () { return false; }
}
```

does indeed have a prop2 defined?

`prop2` will always be defined as a function, but for some objects it is not required and will not be defined.

I tried what was suggested here: [How to determine if Native JavaScript Object has a Property/Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595766/how-to-determine-if-native-javascript-object-has-a-property-method) but I don't think it works for anonymous objects .

Comment: There's not much difference between anonymous and non-anonymous objects in JavaScript. They are the same under the cover.

Answer (score 349, accepted):

`typeof myObj.prop2 === 'function';` will let you know if the function is defined.

```
if(typeof myObj.prop2 === 'function') {
    alert("It's a function");
} else if (typeof myObj.prop2 === 'undefined') {
    alert("It's undefined");
} else {
    alert("It's neither undefined nor a function. It's a " + typeof myObj.prop2);
}
```

Comment: try this if you want to check with dynamic variable `if(typeof myObj[propoeryStr] === 'function') { ... }`

Comment: ...won't this also alert("It's a function") if prop2 is a class? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Yes - but a `class` constructor `isA` `function`.

Answer (score 56):

You want `hasOwnProperty()`:

```js
var myObj1 = { 
 prop1: 'no',
 prop2: function () { return false; }
}
var myObj2 = { 
 prop1: 'no'
}

console.log(myObj1.hasOwnProperty('prop2')); // returns true
console.log(myObj2.hasOwnProperty('prop2')); // returns false
```

References: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/328kyd6z(VS.85).aspx), [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/js/hasOwnProperty.html).

Comment: this will not work if you have placed a dom node within a self-made object, eg if `var my_obj = {'node1': document.createElement('div')};` then `my_obj.node1.hasOwnProperty('cloneNode')` is false. however Sean's solution will correctly return true: `typeof my_obj.node1.cloneNode === 'function'`

Comment: Won't work if you are looking for a method that was defined in the prototype.

Comment: @Wilt question specified anonymous object literal.

Comment: @artlung Yes your answer is good for the question, just wanted to leave that comment here for others who might be looking for similar a solution working in other cases (like me)... Didn't mean to disqualify your answer.

Comment: Doesn't handle the case where the property is defined, but is not a function.

Answer (score 26):

### 3 Options

1. `typeof myObj.prop2 === 'function'` if the property name is not dynamic/generated
2. `myObj.hasOwnProperty('prop2')` if the property name is dynamic, and only check if it is direct property (not down the prototype chain)
3. `'prop2' in myObj` if the property name is dynamic, and check down the prototype chain

Answer (score 8):

What do you mean by an "anonymous object?" `myObj` is not anonymous since you've assigned an object literal to a variable. You can just test this:

```
if (typeof myObj.prop2 === 'function')
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I am surprised that all answers ensure that the method exists *and* it is a function, when the OP does only want to check for existence. To know it is a function (as many have stated) you may use:

```
typeof myObj.prop2 === 'function'
```

But you may also use as a condition:

```
typeof myObj.prop2
```

Or even:

```
myObj.prop2
```

This is so because a function evaluates to `true` and `undefined` evaluates to `false`. So if you know that if the member exists it may only be a function, you can use:

```
if(myObj.prop2) {
  <we have prop2>
}
```

Or in an expression:

```
myObj.prop2 ? <exists computation> : <no prop2 computation>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it must be `if (typeof myObj.prop1 != "undefined") {...}`

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, method)](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins)

> In ECMAScript 5.1, Object.create was added, which enables the creation of objects with a specified [[Prototype]]. Object.create(null) is a common pattern used to create objects that will be used as a Map. This can lead to errors when it is assumed that objects will have properties from Object.prototype. This rule prevents calling some Object.prototype methods directly from an object.

> Additionally, objects can have properties that shadow the builtins on Object.prototype, potentially causing unintended behavior or denial-of-service security vulnerabilities. For example, it would be unsafe for a webserver to parse JSON input from a client and call hasOwnProperty directly on the resulting object, because a malicious client could send a JSON value like {"hasOwnProperty": 1} and cause the server to crash.

> To avoid subtle bugs like this, it's better to always call these methods from Object.prototype. For example, foo.hasOwnProperty("bar") should be replaced with Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar").

```js
const myObj = { 
  prop1: 'no',
  prop2: function () { return false }
}

console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, 'prop2'))
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, 'prop3'))
```