# Discover what methods javascript object has

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that renders just fine. On the page is a control and I wanted to set the visibility to hidden. I can get a handle on the object just fine but then when I went to use what I thought were pretty typical methods such as:

```
.setVisible(false);
```

or

```
.css("visibility", "hidden");
```

I got the object doesn't support method error.

Now to solve my visibility problem there was a containing div for the control so I just set the div to hidden.

```
$('#footer_statecode').hide();
```

My question however for the future is how would I discover the methods supported by an object.

My google searches came close such as this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007460/javascript-check-if-anonymous-object-has-a-method) post but in these example the person had a specific method they were looking for. I am interested in seeing everything available....and it doesn't have to be via an alert(); I'd be just fine using some capability in the different browsers Developer tools (F12).

Thank you once again for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list the properties of a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: In Firefox just type `$('#footer_statecode').` in the console and a list of methods will appear. Im not sure about Chrome.

Comment: `var support = "method" in obj;`

Comment: @Andy Interestingly...for me in IE & Chrome $('#footer_statecode') in the F12 console resulted in full blown object exploration while firefox only gave me []?? Anyway it worked as you say. Thank You!

Comment: @A.Wolff am I missing something in your comment? Wouldn't that be a nice concise way to find a method IF you knew what to look for?...which I don't.

Comment: If you know what to looking for, yes, otherwise you have to iterate throught the propeties of object. But following your example, you could: `var supportSetVisible = "setVisible" in obj;` But anyway, you are supposed to know the type of object you are calling method on

Comment: @Andy FYI, chrome does the same ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this. It won't include built-in JavaScript methods (ex Array.prototype.push)

```
var methods = [];
for (var prop in object) {
  if (typeof object[prop] === "function") {
    methods.push(prop);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not checking on purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can find it like this:

```
function getMethods(prop)
{ 
    var res = [];
    for(var prop in x) {
        if(typeof x[prop] == 'function') {
            res.push(prop);
        }
      }
        return res;
    }
```

You can also look at the [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: You are setting `res` to an empty array on each iteration. You are also returning inside the loop -- this will retrieve only one method.